# How long will it take two clocks to show the same time once again?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are two analog wall clocks on a wall. On 1st January 2000 daytime, John
 sees the watches through a mirror placed on the opposite wall showing 10:30
 A.M. and 1:30 P.M. respectively. The first watch runs 1 minute fast and the
 second watch runs 1 minute slow daily. When will these two watches show the
 same time?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Right now the first is **three hours** behind the second. Every day, the first one catches up by a minute and the second one slows down by a minute, which means that, in total, each day causes them to be **two minutes** closer to each other. Can you take it from here?